# Any policy on good edits with bad comments?

Tags: discussion, moderation, editing

I just reviewed an edit where the actual edit was good, but the comment that came with the edit was borderline offensive.  Photo of the edit with its comment below.

What I did was accept the edit and then improve it in order to overwrite the edit comment.  Is that the right approach?

[image: photo of proposed edit with its comment]

Comment: Note that the reason why the actual edit is good is that the product name is actually "Chai Latte".

Comment: I'm not very experienced with the site yet so I'll try to answer it with my knowledge of it. I don't think a policy really exists still in Stack Exchange implying what to do with edit comments. the edit comments are just there, and for the most part, they're ignored. yes, it feels a bit offensive IMO, so I think it's right to do it, but some wouldn't really care, like me most of the time. you can do what you want to help the community, after all, *we* run this site. also, I took a look at the revisions and the edit comment *is* there since you approved it, then edited it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the *top* edit comment though, so it's not as visible.